# Retrieve a list of data from Firebase Database, and compose it as a message for an email

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data stored in the Firebase Database, its structure is given in the image below

[image]

In the products node, each of the child has items productName and quantity. Upon button press, i want to retrieve these data, from each child. Then set them as the body of an email and arrange them such that they're separated by a comma, then at the end display the total price

productName1, quantity1

productName2, quantity2

productName3, quantity3

total =

The solution seems a bit simple i think. But since I am new to Android Studio and Firebase, i lack the skill to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: sorry i forgot to mention, i'll be using intent to send Email.

Comment: show your code how you are doing it now

Comment: @yugen Do you want a list of the objects of products ?

Comment: the list of the values of "products" and also of "quantities", as i have mentioned above, arranged in that particular order. Apologies if i am not clear enough. English isn't my native language

Comment: @UmarHussain i haven't done anything actually. i tried to use valueEventListeners to retrieve the data, but i don't quite know how to use them in retrieving multiple data. I can somehow manage with getting a single item. Then displaying them in that particular arrangement is the next of my difficulties.

Comment: I have posted the answer below, Tell me if you're still stucking !

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me where ever you get stucked !

```
        FirebaseDatabase databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                                         getReference("Requests");
        ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;
        ArrayList<Requests> requestList = new ArrayList<>();
        mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    try{
                                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                Requests obj = postSnapshot.getValue(Requests.class);
                                                requestList.add(obj)
                                        }
                                        //You will get the list of request objects here and you can parse products from it via loop
                                        //Handle your code here further
                                    } catch(Exception e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                          };

        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
```

Requests.Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Requests {

    String address,name,phone,status,total;
    ArrayList<Products> productsArrayList;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public ArrayList<Products> getProductsArrayList() {
        return productsArrayList;
    }

    public void setProductsArrayList(ArrayList<Products> productsArrayList) {
        this.productsArrayList = productsArrayList;
    }
}
```

Product.Class

```
public class Products {

    String price,productId,productName,quantity,userPhone;


    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getUserPhone() {
        return userPhone;
    }

    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Is there is any other method provided by firebase to do so?

Comment: he may already have implemented that,you dont know what he needs how can you be so sure about that?Isn't it maybe that are the same guy who is asking the question?just to get points?

Comment: Hi @D's I agree with you but I think the way he asked the question doesn't reflect the same.